# Change element's background color in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, colors

I am trying to create an function that will change the color of my element (`id="box"`) when called with the ID and color name. How can I do this?

This is the code:

```js
function color(id, idColor) {
  id = '';
  idColor = '';
  object = document.getElementById(id).style.background = idColor;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="color()">Click me</div>
```

Comment: There is no question here.

Comment: @cord Your question seems to be incomplete. :(

Comment: yeah sorry I know,

Comment: I am trying to create an function that will change my elements (box = id ), and the color when I pass trought the id's name and color

Comment: What is the point of having `id` and `idColor` as arguments if they get overriden imediately at the begining? And you are not passing parameters to `color` when you call it inside the `onclick` should be somrthing like: `onclick="color(/*some value for id here*/, /*some value for idColor here*/)"`

Comment: Is their a better way that I can write this to make the code work ?

Comment: I used Id and idcolor, because I though that is how you pass through and varibile

Answer (score 0):

The question is rather incomplete. But if I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you want to change the color of an element by passing the `id` and `color` to a function. You can do it like this.

**Method 1**

Invoke `color` function with `id` and `color`.

```js
function color(id, idColor) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.background = idColor;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="color('box','red')">Click me</div>
```

**Method 2**

Using `event` object, instead of passing `id` explicitly each time. This is a slightly better approach, as you don't have to worry about the attributes on the div (like `id` in this case). The `event` object provides a `target` attribute which allows us to grab the `div` node directly (without needing to do `document.getElementById(id)`).

```js
function color(event,idColor) {
   event.target.style.background = idColor;
}
```

```html
<div id="box" onclick="color(event,'red')">Click me</div>
```

Invoke color only by passing color.

Comment: Thanks this works, Ill try my best to be clearer with my question.

Comment: So if I wanted to pass the width and height, could I do something like this ?    function
  color( id , idColor, width , height )
  {
    px   = "px";
    width = " "+px;
    height = " "+px;
    console.log(id);
    document.getElementById(id).style.background = idColor;
    document.getElementById(id).width = width;
    document.getElementById(id).width = height;

  }     <div id="box" onclick="color('box','red', '400px', '400px')"></div>

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this . Give some height and Width to Div to click on it

```
<div id ="mybox" onclick="changeColor('mybox','blue')" style="height:100px; width:100px"></div>

function changeColor(id,idcolor){
            document.getElementById(id).style.backgroundColor =idcolor;
        }
```

I hope this is your answer.

Comment: OK cool Thanks that did work, so if I want to pass the height and width,